# svn to git migration non-existant large file

Tags: git, svn

I used svn-git to import an SVN repository

```
svn2git/bin/svn2git http://svn.domain.ltd.uk/svn/dev/ECMC --username pingg
```

When trying to push to github, it complains about large file size,

```
 [kshk@localhost#] git push --set-upstream origin master
Counting objects: 206115, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49987/49987), done.
Writing objects: 100% (206115/206115), 441.62 MiB | 5.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 206115 (delta 109860), reused 195000 (delta 109594)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: df39ad042c3f6d4103db7f474334f862
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File cloud/StoreStockIndexer/data/StockData.txt is 134.53 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:myrepo-ag/myrepo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myrepo-ag/myrepo.git'
```

However this file `cloud/StoreStockIndexer/data/StockData.txt` does not exist on the repository and neither on the SVN repository.

Is this possibly due to corrupt svn-git migration?

I have added the file to ```.gitignore`` however that also does not work... Any idea on fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that file *has been* checked into the SVN at some point and deleted afterwards there will be a commit object in git. You can use [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) 
to remove it, if necessary:

```
bfg --delete-files cloud/StoreStockIndexer/data/StockData.txt  myrepo.git
```